# SASS Extends Dynamic

Tags: css, sass

I have a SASS function I am using to calculate column width:

```
@for $i from 1 through $number-of-columns {
  .column-#{$i} {
     width: ($i / $number-of-columns) * 100%;
  }
}
```

Which works great and outputs as expected:

```
.column-12 {
  width: 100%;
}
.column-11 {
  width: 91.666667%;
}
.column-10 {
  width: 83.333334%;
}
```

But now I would like to apply a style to all of those classes like so:

```
column-1, column-2, column-3...column-12 {
    display: block;
}
```

Is there an easy way to do this using `@extend`?

Comment: put display:block; in your loop

Comment: I added a class `all-columns` which holds the attributes needed and I just `@extend .all-columns` inside the loop. Not the clean way I really wanted, but it does the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to illustrate how to use **`@extend`** for this. You would want to define a **placeholder rule** (e.g. `%all-columns`), that gets extended in each iteration by another class. Like so:

```
%all-columns {
  display: block;
}

@for $i from 1 through $number-of-columns {
  .column-#{$i} {
     width: ($i / $number-of-columns) * 100%;
     @extend %all-columns;
  }
}
```

### [DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/8722420)

output CSS:

```
.column-1, .column-2, .column-3, .column-4, .column-5, .column-6, .column-7, .column-8, .column-9, .column-10, .column-11, .column-12 {
  display: block;
}

.column-1 {
  width: 8.33333%;
}

.column-2 {
  width: 16.66667%;
}

...
```

But if you want to avoid such a long selector, you should consider an attribute selector, like the solution suggested in [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21466380/sass-extends-dynamic/21466666#21466666).

Comment: No, a long selector is exactly what I am looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `[attr^=val]` selector to target all elements whose `class` begins with `column-`. This would prevent duplicating selectors/rules and minimize the size of your resulting CSS.

[Demo of technique](http://jsfiddle.net/3uHU5/)

```
@for $i from 1 through $number-of-columns {
  .column-#{$i} {
    width: ($i / $number-of-columns) * 100%;
  }
}

[class^="column-"] {
  display:block;
]
```

Comment: Why would someone dow-vote this ... it's a brilliant suggestion. +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
.column {
    display: block;
    @for $i from 1 through $number-of-columns {
        .column-#{$i} {
            width: ($i / $number-of-columns) * 100%;
        }
    }
}
```

Then just apply the `column` class to the div in addition to the `column-1`

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, but it just adds an unwanted class. I was looking for a way around this.

Answer (score 0):

```
.column {
    @for $i from 1 through $number-of-columns {
        .column-#{$i} {
            width: ($i / $number-of-columns) * 100%;
            display: block;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought of this as well. It's close, but it is adding `display: block` to every class producing n extra lines. I'd rather list the classes then just apply it once.